# Flutter creates errors after upgrading pre 1.12 Android project

Tags: java, android, flutter, migration

I'm working on a Flutter app that has been created *prior to 1.12*, and while running the app or executing `flutter pub get`, I get a warning regarding this upgrade, which leads me to: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects

I've followed all the steps under ***Add-to-app migration*** and when running the app, I get some errors for ***path_provider, shared_preferences, and flutter_secure_storage*** which doesn't allow the app to run.

Does someone else encounter a similar issue? or does someone know what would be done in this situation?

One approach that I've read, would be to create a new project and copy the contents of the current one in the newly created one, but somehow I don't find it really good, I wanted to migrate the current one.

**Errors**:

```android
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method readAll on channel plugins.it_nomads.com/flutter_secure_storage)
```

**Full stack trace error:**

```android
[ +414 ms] E/flutter ( 9811): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9811): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:157:7)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9811): <asynchronous suspension>
[        ] E/flutter ( 9811): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:332:12)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9811): #2      getApplicationDocumentsDirectory (package:path_provider/path_provider.dart:40:22)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9811): #3      FavoriteDbProvider.init (package:someapp/db/favorite_db_provider.dart:25:42)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9811): #4      new FavoriteDbProvider (package:someapp/db/favorite_db_provider.dart:16:5)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9811): #5      new FavoriteBloc (package:someapp/bloc/favorite_bloc.dart:13:49)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9811): #6      _BlocProvidersState._initBloc (package:someapp/app/app_bloc_providers.dart:126:20)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9811): #7      _BlocProvidersState.initState (package:someapp/app/app_bloc_providers.dart:104:5)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9811): #8      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4765:58)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9811): #9      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9811): #10     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9811): #11     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3324:20)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9811): #12     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4652:16)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9811): #13     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4800:11)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9811): #14     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4343:5)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9811): #15     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2730:33)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9811): #16     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:913:20)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9811): #17     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:302:5)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9811): #18     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1117:15)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9811): #19     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1055:9)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9811): #20     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:971:5)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9811): #21     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9811): #22     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9811): #23     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9811): #24     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:251:10)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9811): #25     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:209:3)
```

**Application.java**

```android
package com.someview.someapp;

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import io.flutter.plugins.androidalarmmanager.AlarmService;
import io.flutter.plugins.androidalarmmanager.AndroidAlarmManagerPlugin;

import com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;
import com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin;
import io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.SharedPreferencesPlugin;
import io.flutter.plugins.pathprovider.PathProviderPlugin;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService;
public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistrantCallback {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    AlarmService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
    FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
    // manually load each plugin required by the AlarmService isolate task!
    AndroidAlarmManagerPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.androidalarmmanager.AndroidAlarmManagerPlugin"));

    // add FlutterNotifications plugin register
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin"));

    //add PathProviderPlugin plugin register  if you work with Access Path Device
    PathProviderPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.pathprovider.PathProviderPlugin"));

    //add SqflitePlugin plugin register  if you work with sqflite
    SqflitePlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin"));

    //add SharedPreferencesPlugin plugin register  if you work with share preferences
    SharedPreferencesPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.SharedPreferencesPlugin"));
    FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
  }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```android
package com.someview.someapp;

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
//import android.os.Bundle;
//import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
//import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity  {
//  @Override
//  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
//  }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```android
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.someview.someapp">

    <!-- The INTERNET permission is required for development. Specifically,
         flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <!-- AlarmManager plugin permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:allowBackup="false">
        <meta-data
          android:name="flutterEmbedding"
          android:value="2" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="CHANNEL"
            android:value="asdchannel" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
                 until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
                 there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
                 defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- AlarmManager plugin requirements -->
        <service
            android:name="io.flutter.plugins.androidalarmmanager.AlarmService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
            android:exported="false"/>
        <receiver
            android:name="io.flutter.plugins.androidalarmmanager.AlarmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false"/>
        <receiver
            android:name="io.flutter.plugins.androidalarmmanager.RebootBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- LocalNotifications plugin requirements -->
        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Thanks!